# html / web scraping C# specific file structure

Tags: c#

I would prefer to do this in C#, but if the best is in R or Python, I could push a file with the results via one of those if needed.  Doing this for a friend so wanted to do everything in one easy to use exe.

I am looking for the best way to pull a line from a couple hundred HTML files, and it is always the 23rd line in each html file.  (if you open the file for editing)

the iteration through the files is no big deal but what I am looking for is a way to collect just the 4th td in the tr class=g, however there are numerous identical tr classes in the file

```
<tr class=g><td class=s1>Talent</td><td>Good</td><td>Average</td><td>Poor</td><td>Brilliant</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td></tr>
```

in the above example the "brilliant" is what I am trying to find, but only if the position has the word brilliant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you're looking for from us. Do you just want to iterate over some files and pull the 23rd line from each? You talk about the 4th or 5th tr, but there's only one tr in your sample. Please try something and show your attempted code as an [mre].

Comment: yes pulling the 23rd line from each html file, editing the above to clarify since you are correct it's the 4th <td> not <tr>

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you mean by line 23. Do you mean the 23rd line in the file, or the 23rd line in a browser?

If the first case, the simplest way is to simply load each file and scan for new lines. From that, you'll be able to determine when you've reached the 23rd line.

However, if you want to load the HTML and be able to scan for elements using jQuery-like selectors such as `tr .g`, I would recommend something like my HTML parser [HtmlMonkey](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.HtmlMonkey/). This library will parse the HTML and then let you easily search for elements. It's a NuGet package but is also available on Git Hub.

Comment: 23rd line in the html file

Comment: And now you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the Nuget Package HtmlAgilityPack.
Then you can do it like this

```
var html = @"<tr class=g><td class=s1>Talent</td><td>Good</td><td>Average</td><td>Poor</td><td>Brilliant</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td></tr>";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (var tr in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
{
    // loop tds
    foreach (var td in tr.ChildNodes)
    {
        ...
    }

    // or access node directly
    var val4 = tr.ChildNodes[3].InnerText;
}
```

To get Line Number 23 you can use

```
var line23 = File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(22).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be scraping HTML text, I would also suggest using HtmlAgilityPack in the following way.

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    List<string> files = new List<string>(); // Define your list of files
    List<string> valuesNeeded = new List<string>(); // These are the values from each doc
    foreach(string file in files)
    {
        doc.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllLines(file).ElementAt(23));
        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr[@class='g']//td[4]"); // td starts with index 1.
        if (node != null) 
            valuesNeeded.Add(node.InnerText);
    }
```

**Process**

- Read in the list of files
- Iterate through the list and read each file. Get only line 23 and load it up in HtmlDocument
- Find the first node that has `tr` with class name `g` and its 4th `td` element.
- If it is not null, add it to resulting list.

Comment: @lucyinthesky please do upvote / mark the post answered if it answered your original post